# Постоянная проверка if

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код

```
if ( $("#payment").hasClass("checked") ) {

document.getElementById("uniform-id_carrier1300").style.display='none';

} else {
document.getElementById("uniform-id_carrier1300").style.display='block';
}
```

При его выполнение все работает, но один раз. Хотелось бы, чтобы шла постоянная проверка названия класса. То есть, если элемент имеет название класса "чекед", то скрыть элемент, если у этого элемента нету в названии класса "чекед" то показать.

Comment: А зачем Вы, используя Jquery, пишете "document.getElementById"??

Comment: @humster_spb, так быстрее же)

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить что познаний в js нет. К сожалению (( Код выше был взят из интернета.

Comment: Тебе нужен обработчик `onchange`, который следит за изменениями, а для соответствующего обработчика нужен код, который "тугглит" стиль для отображения элемента (врубает дисплей блок или же убирает в зависимости от того, какое значение у него сейчас).

Answer (score 3):

В реализацию вашего чекбокса можно добавить эмиссию события смены состояния.

Найдите место, где меняется класс `checked`. Это либо `.toggleClass('checked')`, либо пара `addClass/removeClass` в разных местах.

В каждом добавьте эмиссию события change:

```
$(this).trigger('change', [checked]); // checked - bool состояние чекбокса
```

Вместо `this` возможно придётся написать другую переменную, указывающую на меняющийся элемент.

Тогда, в клиентском коде вы сможете отловить это событие:

```
$('#payment').on('change', function(e, checked){
  $('#blockToToggle')[checked?'show':'hide']();
});
```

Comment: Мой чекбокс сделан с помощью таблиц. Как понять что был выбран tr ? При выборе, добавляется в название класса "checked". Насколько я понимаю, можно отловить только по названию класса.

Comment: вот там, где добавляется класс и добавьте trigger

Comment: `if ( $("#payment").hasClass("checked") ) {

$(this).trigger('change', [checked]);

} else {
$(this).trigger('change', [checked2]);
}`

Comment: код выше не работает. Что не так?

Comment: Всё не так. Вам нужен код с `.addClass('checked')` или toggle

Answer (score 1):

Если предположить, что вы не можете изменять существующий код приложения, то можно использовать [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) для отслеживания изменений значения атрибута `class`.

В вашем случае, код мог бы выглядеть как-то так:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.filter(function(mutation) {
        return (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'class');
    }).forEach(function(mutation) {
        if ($(mutation.target).is('.checked')) {
            $('#extra-field').hide();
        } else {
            $('#extra-field').show();
        }
    });    
});

observer.observe($('#payment').get(0), {attributes: true});
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/pqd9gLqn/3/) на JSFiddle.

**Замечение:**

Не смотря на то, что подход с использованием `MutationObserver` вполне работоспособен, я бы использовал его только как "последнее средство". Это слишком уж мощное и не очевидное решение тривиальных задач, вроде вашей.

Вместо этого, я посоветовал бы вам переписать ваш кастомный checkbox так, чтобы он генерировал событие `onchange` (или аналогичное). О том, как это сделать, написано в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/635655/182771).

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте проверку на значение чекбокса при его изменении, и в этом же месте скрывайте или показывайте нужный блок.

Следить за изменением можно этим - https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Как вы поняли, что там чекбокс?

Comment: дело в том, что там не select, а чекбокс сделанный с помощью div.

Comment: А когда ставите класс checked, то не можете сразу же скрыть/показать нужный блок?

Comment: @vp_arth по названию класса

Comment: @anme change насколько я понял работает только на поля. В моем случае проверить возможно только по названию класса.